# How can i wrap text before this symbol without destroying existing html

Tags: jquery

Trying to wrap all words prior to the "," in each td cell. Note that words prior to "," in each cell will be different , so can not target a specific word per se

Existing html

```
<td class="name">
 <a href="" title="" class="">lastName, firstName</a>
</td>
```

Desired outcome

```
<td class="name">
 <a href="" title="" class=""><span>lastName</span>, firstName</a>
</td>
```

Attempts, all of which destroy the a href structure, I need to keep the `a` tag with class, title and href as is and just wrap the word/words prior to ","

```
$('td.name').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/,.*$/, '<span class="after">$&</span>'));
});

$('td.name').html(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/([^,]+)(,)/, '$1<span class="auther">$2</span>$3');
});

$('td.name').html(function (i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(.*?,)/, '<span>$1</span>')
});
```

Comment: Your code worked fine, just needed to target the `td>a` instead of the `td`: https://jsfiddle.net/bojnx4fq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) for each `<td>` and use it to find all the text nodes, passing in a filter to locate only the ones containing commas.

From there, you can split the text into chunks and map each pre-comma chunk to a new `<span>` then [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) the entire text node with the new set of nodes.

```js
const createSpan = textContent => Object.assign(
  document.createElement("span"),
  { textContent }
)

const filter = {
  acceptNode: node =>
    node.data.includes(",") ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT
}

document.querySelectorAll("td.name").forEach(td => {
  const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    td,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, // select only text nodes
    filter,               // filter for content with commas
    false
  )
  
  let node
  
  while (node = treeWalker.nextNode()) {
    // split the text on comma, keeping the delimiter
    const chunks = node.data.split(/(?=,)/)
    
    // keep the last chunk as-is
    const last = chunks.pop()
    
    // replace the text node with the new node set
    node.replaceWith(...chunks.map(createSpan), last)
  }
})
```

```css
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" title="" class="">lastName, firstName</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">
      <a href="" title="" class="">no commas</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I really didn't see any use for jQuery here.

Comment: why not just look for all `a` tags under a `td.name` and prepend a span node?

Comment: @Jhecht I thought from ops question that the contents of the table cells wasn't known. Even the `<a>` tags might be optional

Comment: fair enough assumption, but from my understanding of the question the OP was trying to make sure that the attributes of the `a` tag didn't get updated, which was the issue of their solution.

Comment: @Jhecht I thought it was because their solution was wrapping the opening `<a>` tag with a `<span>`. If the `<a>` tag was always a given, I figure they would have just gone with something like [Dexterity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69834834/283366)

Answer (score 0):

Glad you like jQuery, this few lines will get you going. Cheers!

```js
$('.my_name').each(function() {
var my_text = $(this).find("a").text();
var my_wrap = my_text.replace(/[^,]*/, '<span class="my_class">$&</span>');
$(this).find("a:contains(',')").empty().append(my_wrap);
});
```

```css
.my_class { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <td class="my_name">
      <a href="my_href.com" title="" class="">lastName, firstName</a>
    </td>
    
    <td class="my_name">
      <a href="my_href.com" title="" class="">td 2 not affected</a>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
//Output
<a href="my_href.com" title="" class=""><span class="my_class">lastName</span>, firstName</a>
```